# SQL History in SAP HANA Studio

Tags: sql

Is there is possible to retrieve the SQL History in SAP HANA Studio?

If so where?
So far I didn't find in in the menus.
Neither did an internet research result to a solution.

The only work-around I have in mind is to use either SQuirreL

Or is there an eclipse plug-in?